# show html5 videos only on desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, html5-video

I have this code which populates the src attributes of the sources if the user is not on mobile:

```
 if($.browser.mobile)
   {
       console.log("is mobile")
      // it is mobile browser
   }
   else
   {
     console.log("is desktop")
      // no mobile browser
      var sources = document.querySelectorAll('video#patient-video source');
     // Define the video object this source is contained inside
     var video = document.querySelector('video#patient-video');
     for(var i = 0; i<sources.length;i++) {
       sources[i].setAttribute('src', sources[i].getAttribute('data-src'));
     }
     // If for some reason we do want to load the video after, for desktop as opposed to mobile (I'd imagine), use videojs API to load
     video.load();
     video.muted= "muted";
   }
```

To check if it's a mobile browser, I use the plugin:

```
detectmobilebrowser.js
```

My HTML is as follows:

```
 <video id="patient-video" width="100%" preload="none" poster="../../assets/img/patient-home-1600.jpg" autoplay loop>
            <source data-src="../../assets/video/patient-home-video-comp.mp4" src="" type="video/mp4">
            <source data-src="../../assets/video/patient-home-video-comp.webm" src="" type="video/webm">
            <source data-src="../../assets/video/patient-home-video-comp.ogv" src="" type="video/ogg">
          </video>
```

This works fine for one specific video, but how can I adapt the Javscript so that it does the same for all videos on the page.

Comment: you can use media queries to detect the size of the browser

Comment: @BenPhilipp there is no need for jquery foreach, the OP just needs to use a class instead of an id

Comment: @RachelGallen Yes. Or a type, or some other common denominator - what I meant by "something like" `.each()` is not "they need jQuery", I was just talking about a general way to collect the target objects; point being it's not a mobile / desktop issue but a collection issue. I __did__ overlook the fact that they were indeed already setting up a collection because it was fishing for an ID - apologies

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a class not an id if you are using multiple vids of the same name

```
if($.browser.mobile)
   {
       console.log("is mobile")
      // it is mobile browser
   }
   else
   {
     console.log("is desktop")
      // no mobile browser
      var sources = document.querySelectorAll('video.patient-video source');
     // Define the video object this source is contained inside
     var video = document.querySelector('video.patient-video');
     for(var i = 0; i<sources.length;i++) {
       sources[i].setAttribute('src', sources[i].getAttribute('data-src'));
     }
     // If for some reason we do want to load the video after, for desktop as opposed to mobile (I'd imagine), use videojs API to load
     video.load();
     video.muted= "muted";
   }
```

note the dot instead of the hash tag. You don't even need the 'video' before it. Don't forget to update your html accordingly

it should be

```
<video class="patient-video" width="100%" preload="none" poster="../../assets/img/patient-home-1600.jpg" autoplay loop>
            <source data-src="../../assets/video/patient-home-video-comp.mp4" src="" type="video/mp4">
            <source data-src="../../assets/video/patient-home-video-comp.webm" src="" type="video/webm">
            <source data-src="../../assets/video/patient-home-video-comp.ogv" src="" type="video/ogg">
          </video>
```

Comment: if you have #patient-video in your css, amend it to read .patient-video{etc}